# How to pass Ctrl-C to the guest when running qemu with -nographic?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu

I configured Qemu's grub the following way:

```
GRUB_TERMINAL="serial console"
GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND="serial"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="..console=ttyS0"
```

and run the `qemu` process with the `-nographic` command line option. These enables to use the current terminal for the serial console and `qemu` monitor console. However now, anytime I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> inside the running VM, it is intercepted by `qemu` and shuts the process down.

How am I supposed to pass <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or any other keystroke involving <kbd>CTRL</kbd> in Qemu?

Answer (score 21):

In your shell, before you run qemu, run "stty intr ^]" to change the interrupt key from ^c to ctrl-]

That way, ctrl-c will be passed through to qemu, but you can still interrupt qemu itself by pressing ctrl-]

Comment: To override Ctrl-Z (backgrounding) too, there is `stty susp ^]`. For Ctrl-\ (quit), use `stty quit ^]`. With multiple definitions for a single char, this is the order of precedence: intr quit susp.

Comment: To override all characters that generate signals (like SIGINT and SIGSTOP), use `stty -isig`.  To save the and restore the settings, use `(trap "stty $(stty -g)" 0; stty -isig; qemu-system-....)`

Answer (score 6):

You can try using the `sendkey` command using `-monitor stdio`. Though apparently the `-display none -serial mon:stdio` option should pass <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> through to the guest.

You can also create a [monitor](http://wiki.qemu.org/download/qemu-doc.html#pcsys_005fmonitor) socket, like this:

```
qemu -display none -monitor unix:/tmp/qemu-monitor,server,nowait
```

And then, connect to the monitor to use sendkey with `socat` like this:

```
socat - UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/qemu-monitor
```

You can now send your keys, like this:

```
(qemu) sendkey ctrl-c
sendkey ctrl-c
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me how can I 'jump' into qemy monitor console (ie. what keystroke should I press), if I run qemu in the PuTTY terminal?

Comment: In GUI - Ctrl + Alt then Shift + 2 to switch to the monitor, or Shift-1 to switch back to guest OS. That doesn't work in console. There you can use the socket approach, and open up another `screen` window and connect to it via `socat`. You can also use `-monitor stdio` to redirect to your terminal instead.

Answer (score 5):

**Remove `-monitor` or add `-serial mon:stdio`**

As of QEMU 2.10.1, Ubuntu 17.10, `Ctrl-C` does get passed by default to the guest without problem when using `-nographic`.

However, if you also use the `-monitor` option, behavior changes, and the `Ctrl-C` kills QEMU instead.

This is how `-monitor` would normally be used: [How to switch to the QEMU control panel with -nographics? | Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/488263/how-to-switch-to-the-qemu-control-panel-with-nographics/1311906#1311906)

If you need `-monitor`, you can get Ctrl+C back with `-serial mon:stdio`: [How to run qemu with -nographic and -monitor but still be able to send Ctrl+C to the guest and quit with Ctrl+A X? | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49716931/how-to-run-qemu-with-nographic-and-monitor-but-still-be-able-to-send-ctrlc-to)