# Prevent qemu from hijacking input

Tags: gnu-screen, qemu

I am trying to run gnu screen in a virtual machine. To create a new screen window, I press ctrl+a c, but this key combination makes the qemu monitor appear instead. How do I send these keystrokes to the guest?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167165/how-to-pass-ctrl-c-to-the-guest-when-running-qemu-with-nographic#171707

Comment: Doesn't work. Maybe because I'm using "guix system vm" which is a wrapper around qemu that possibly resets environment variables or the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QEMU in `-nographic` mode](https://qemu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/system/mux-chardev.html) uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> as its own escape character.

To send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to the emulated system, you need to double it; so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> will create a new window in your `screen` session.

You can change QEMU’s escape character using the `-echr` option, followed by the ASCII code of the key you want to use; for example,

```
qemu -echr 2 ...
```

would use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.